# Should IBOulets and IBActions be private, internal, or public in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

This topic hasn't been discussed much in newer releases of swift. And in older topics, there aren't many informative answers. I don't know if there are any advantages of making outlets and actions private/internal/public...

Comment: all depends upon your requirement. private works only inside your class not outside it.public is acceptable from anywhere. Inline within same package.so all depends how you want to access data .

Comment: I can't think of any particular scenarios where someone would want to subclass a class with outlets/actions. Would that even be good practice? If not, they should always be private, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your needs

***internal***: if you're creating a custom library or framework, you won't want that people that uses it, modify values of some internal outlets (or any other variables) right?, so in this case you'd probably use **internal**, because you want these variables to accessible within your module.

***fileprivate***: with this one, you won't be able to change the value of your outlet if you subclass.

But, why would you need to subclass? Let's see this example

```
class CDWriteMessageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var someTitleLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.someTitleLabel.text = "Write a Message" // Title by default
    }

}
```

This is a controller to create a message for somebody. Then you realize that you also need to give the ability to save the message locally before sending, so you would need to create another controller.

```
class CDDraftMessageViewController: CDWriteMessageViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.someTitleLabel.text = "Draft" // Modifiying the outlet
    }

}
```

As you can see I'm subclassing the controller because I want the same functionality PLUS other stuff as: new title, adding a delete button, save locally, etc. This is one of the principles of SOLID named "Open-closed Principle". For more information: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

And last but not least:

***public***: with this, if you subclass you will be able to modify the value of the variable within your module, but not from outside

Glad to help :)